# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'users.map') REACT NATIVE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

Hello for some reason when I try to map through a state that I am passing through from another component I get this error undefined is not an object ( 'evaluating user.map') and I have no idea why.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, ScrollView} from 'react-native';
import Card from '../../molecules/Card';
import Axios from 'axios';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    //Fetch
    // fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
    //   .then(res => res.json())
    //   .then(json => setUsers(json.data));
    //Axios
    Axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(res =>
      setUsers(res.data.data),
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Users List</Text>

      <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        {users.map(item => (
          <Card
            key={item.id}
            fullName={`${item.first_name} ${item.last_name}`}
            userName={item.userName}
            email={item.email}
            phone={item.phone}
          />
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    paddingTop: 20,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 36,
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  card: {
    marginTop: 15,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  name: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  email: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: 'grey',
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  image: {
    height: 150,
    width: 150,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
});
```

I dont understand what happen when i use that map for my code.
it said "Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'users.map')" Can someone help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The reason is that, when the component renders for the first time, before `useEffect()` can fetch the data, `users` is an empty array therefore `item` is undefined.

Comment: A _quick_ fix could be replacing `users.map(item => ( ...` with `users.length && users.map(item => ( ...`. A _better_ fix would be using the state to keep trace of whether the component is loading the users and display either a loader or the users list as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    //Fetch
    // fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
    //   .then(res => res.json())
    //   .then(json => setUsers(json.data));
    //Axios
    Axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then((res) =>
      console.log(res.data)
    );
  }, []);
```

after testing your code res.data.data doesn't exist you should be setting state to res.data

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the URL `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users` returns an array of users. Meaning that `res.data` will result in the users array.

An array does not have a `data` property, so `res.data.data` will result in `undefined`. Use `setUsers(res.data)` instead.

The current response has the structure:

```json
[ « users » ]
```

`setUsers(res.data.data)` only works if the response has the structure:

```json
{ "data": [ « users » ] }
```